# Derivative of integral in interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $$F(x)=\int_{2}^{x^3}\frac{dt}{\ln t}$$ and $x$ is in $(2,3)$. Find $F'(x)$. Can somebody give me idea how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus + Chain Rule.

Comment: do you mean this here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Comment: Some version of this question appears here quite frequently. Sometimes I wonder why people who post it are so baffled by this.  I can understand being confused about the details of application of the chain rule if one is learning this material for the first time, but why do students who've just days ago sat through lectures on the fundamental theorem fail to realize that that's what this is about? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that:
$$F(u) = \int_a^u f(t)\ dt\implies \frac{d}{du}F(u) = f(u)$$
We are now interested in
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(u(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{u(x)}f(t)\ dt = \left(\frac{d}{du}F(u(x))\right)\frac{du}{dx} = f(u)\frac{du}{dx} = \dots$$

Answer (score 2):

By fundamental theorem of calculus we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t) dt=f(x)$$ and by chain rule we will get $$F'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x^3}\cdot(3x^2)=\frac{3x^2}{3\ln x}=\frac{x^2}{\ln x}$$

Answer (score 2):

if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}h(t)dt$ then $F'(x)=h(x)$ from fundamental theorem.

Now $\int_{a}^{g(x)}h(t)dt=F(g(x))$

so, $\frac{d(F(g(x)))}{dx}=F'(g(x))g'(x)$ by chain rule.